# Django Unit Tests doesn't run in Visual Studio Test Explorer

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to implement my Django (1.11.7, Python 3.6) unit testing in Visual Studio. When I run them in my terminal (python manage.py test) they run fine, while when executing from the VS Test Explorer it fails with an error saying:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

I've read that newer Django versions require an explicit django.setup() to be called, so I've tried to add it both to setUpClass(cls) and to setUpTestData(cls).

```
import django
from datamodel.models import Engagement, BusinessUnit
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.test import TestCase, Client

class TestViewRPA(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(TestViewRPA, cls).setUpClass()
        django.setup()

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        super(TestViewRPA, cls).setUpTestData()
        django.setup()
        User.objects.create_user('dummyuser')
        eng = Engagement.objects.create(name = 'Test Client', owner=User.objects.get(username='dummyuser'))
        businessunit = BusinessUnit.objects.create(name = 'Business Unit', engagement=eng)

    def test_get_industry_segment1(self):
        businessunit = BusinessUnit.objects.get(name = 'Business Unit')
        c = Client()
        response = c.get('/rpa/%d' % businessunit.id)
        self.assertContains(response, 'id":1,"businessunit_set":[{"id":1,', status_code=200)
```

Result from executing from CLI

```
...>env\Scripts\python.exe manage.py test app
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.028s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I have the same issue. Would love to see an answer to this. Surprised this simply does not work with all the python support added to VS.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you are importing **User** from **django.contrib.auth.models** before **django.setup()**

You have already imported django so delete

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

and instead of

```
User.objects.create_user('dummyuser')
```

use django.contrib.auth.models like this

```
django.contrib.auth.models.User.objects.create_user('dummyuser')
```

**or**

if you want to keep everything simple just add **django.setup()** statement before importing anything from **django.contrib.auth.models**